# How to manipulate a div using .draggable(), sliders, and text input using JqueryUI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a circular div that moves along a larger rectangular div. I can move it around using .dragable() as of right now. I need to be able to also move the circle with sliders that have input boxes. The input boxes should also show the current position of the circle. I think this requires getting the current position of the circle but I dont know where to start.

This is what I have so far:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="graphBox">

        <div id="graphBack">
            <div id="head" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="border" id="vertSliderBox">
            <label class="slider-label" for="verticalSlider">Vertical Position:</label>
            <div id="verticalSlider" class="slider"></div>
            <input type="number" class="slider-input" id="verticalInput">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid border">
        <label class="slider-label" for="horizontalSlider">Horizontal Position:</label>
        <div id="horizontalSlider" class="slider"></div>
        <input type="number" class="slider-input" id="horizontalInput">
    </div>

    <script>

        $(function () {

            $("#head").draggable({
                containment: "#graphBack"
            });

            $("#horizontalSlider").slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 0,
                min: -70,
                max: 70,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#head").css("left", ui.value + "px");
                    $("#horizontalInput").val(ui.value);
                }
            });

            $("#horizontalInput").on("change", function () {
                var value = 0;
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#head").css("left", value + "px");
                $("#horizontalSlider").slider("value", value);
            });

            $("#verticalSlider").slider({
                orientation: "vertical",
                range: "min",
                value: 20,
                min: 0,
                max: 40,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#head").css("top", ui.value + "px");
                    $("#verticalInput").val(ui.value);
                }
            });

            $("#verticalInput").on("change", function () {
                var value = 20;
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#head").css("top", value + "px");
                $("#verticalSlider").slider("value", value);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You should include your CSS and make a snippet that way there is a functional example of what you're working with ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code looks like a great start! You are indeed getting the current position of the circle when you move the sliders. You've set up sliders and inputs to control the horizontal and vertical position of the circular div.

One thing that's missing from your code is a way to update the sliders and inputs when the circular div is moved directly by dragging it. You'll need to add some logic inside the draggable function to update the sliders and inputs based on the current position of the div.

You can do that by adding a drag event inside the draggable method, like this:

```
    $("#head").draggable({
        containment: "#graphBack",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var leftPosition = ui.position.left;
            var topPosition = ui.position.top;
            
            // Update the horizontal slider and input
            $("#horizontalSlider").slider("value", leftPosition);
            $("#horizontalInput").val(leftPosition);
            
            // Update the vertical slider and input
            $("#verticalSlider").slider("value", topPosition);
            $("#verticalInput").val(topPosition);
        }
    });
```

Make sure the min and max values for the sliders match the boundaries of the #graphBack container, or else you might find that the sliders don't accurately represent the position of the #head div.

Lastly, you'll want to style the #head div to make it circular and give some size to the #graphBack container, so the containment works properly. You can do that with CSS like this:

```
#graphBack {
    width: 140px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 40px; /* Adjust as needed */
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#head {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

These values should be adjusted to suit your layout. Make sure that the min and max values of your sliders match the boundaries defined by these dimensions.

To center the #head div within the #graphBack container and have the sliders default to those center positions, you will need to make a few adjustments to your JavaScript and CSS.

Here's how you can achieve that:
CSS:
First, you'll need to set the CSS so that the #head starts in the center of the #graphBack container:

```
#graphBack {
    width: 140px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 40px; /* Adjust as needed */
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#head {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /* Center horizontally */
    top: 50%; /* Center vertically */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Adjust for the size of #head */
}
```

JavaScript:
Next, you'll need to update the JavaScript to set the initial values of the sliders and inputs to the center positions:

```
$(function () {
    // Get the center positions
    var centerLeft = $("#graphBack").width() / 2 - $("#head").width() / 2;
    var centerTop = $("#graphBack").height() / 2 - $("#head").height() / 2;

    // Set the initial position of the #head
    $("#head").css({ left: centerLeft, top: centerTop });

    $("#head").draggable({
        containment: "#graphBack",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $("#horizontalSlider").slider("value", ui.position.left);
            $("#horizontalInput").val(ui.position.left);
            $("#verticalSlider").slider("value", ui.position.top);
            $("#verticalInput").val(ui.position.top);
        }
    });

    $("#horizontalSlider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: centerLeft, // Set the initial value
        min: 0,
        max: $("#graphBack").width() - $("#head").width(),
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#head").css("left", ui.value + "px");
            $("#horizontalInput").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

    $("#verticalSlider").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        value: centerTop, // Set the initial value
        min: 0,
        max: $("#graphBack").height() - $("#head").height(),
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#head").css("top", ui.value + "px");
            $("#verticalInput").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

    // Set the initial value of the input boxes
    $("#horizontalInput").val(centerLeft);
    $("#verticalInput").val(centerTop);

    // ... rest of your code
});
```

Make sure to adjust the dimensions of #graphBack and #head in both the CSS and JavaScript (such as the min and max values for the sliders) to match your desired layout.

Now the #head div should start in the center of the #graphBack container, and the sliders and inputs should default to those center positions!

Comment: This helped a lot thanks. Is there a way that I can get the #head to be centered within the #graphback and have the sliders default to those center positions?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the code above to accomplish what you are wanting to do. :)